# Ability to enable Dev Hub / Unlocked Packages for Partner Developer Edition Org

Tags: unlocked-package, dev-hub

I'm using a Partner Developer Edition org to develop features for a managed package (which resides in a different org).

According to the [Winter '19 Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_sfdx_dev_hub.htm), Developer orgs should have the Dev Hub option available if they're not using a namespace.

My Partner Developer Edition org doesn't have a namespace, but I can't see the Dev Hub option in Setup, which is preventing me from using Unlocked Packages to push new functionality to other orgs.

Question: Am I missing anything, or maybe Partner Developer Edition orgs by definition don't have the Dev Hub option?

Comment: Is your partner org quite old?

Comment: This week i created a partner org from here and it has devhub: 
https://partnersignup.salesforce.com/PartnerSignupTrial

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Just created it a month ago.  See my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Enable Dev Hub in Your Org](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_enable_devhub.htm) article, it implies that you can only enable Dev Hub in the Partner Business org:

> Partner trial orgs signed up from the partner community have different scratch org limits. See Scratch Org Allocations for Partners. Partners can create partner edition scratch orgs: Partner Developer, Partner Enterprise, Partner Group, and Partner Professional. ***This feature is available only if creating scratch orgs from a Dev Hub in a partner business org.*** See Supported Scratch Org Editions for Partners in the ISVforce Guide for details.

(You can only create scratch orgs against a Dev Hub enabled org, and same with unlocked packages)