# How to create scrach org when using Partner Developer Edition org?

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, partner-communities, partner-portal, partner

We have a  Partner Developer Edition org which has environment hub. This was created a few years ago. We are in the process of upgrading our development practices to use SFDX and scratch orgs. The Partner Developer Org has environment hub but I do not see developer hubs.

Can I still use scratch orgs from SFDX ? If so, how ? If not, what is our alternative?

[I have seen Brian Miller's answer [Ability to enable Dev Hub / Unlocked Packages for Partner Developer Edition Org](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/269724/ability-to-enable-dev-hub-unlocked-packages-for-partner-developer-edition-org)  but I do not know how to get a Partner Businsess Org .]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have a Partner Business Org ("PBO") for this. Please follow the instructions provided by Salesforce [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/isv1_3_quickstart.htm):

> ... you log a case in the Partner Community to have a Partner Business Org (PBO) provisioned for you.

You'll probably want to talk to them about how to transfer the environment hub to the PBO too, if that is even possible.